# Calculating a percent value reverts to 0

Tags: solidity

My goal is to calculate a **2% interest rate** against a loan denominated in DAI.

`uint256 loanAmount = 500 * 10 ** 18 // $500 in USD`

```
function calculateInterest( uint256 _loanAmount) public view returns (uint256) {
       return 2 / _loanAmount;
    }
```

However, when I execute the function, the value i get is `0`

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Math in Solidity is done entirely using fixed-point numbers.

You can calculate the interest amount as followed:

```
uint256 private interestPercentage  = 2;
function calculateInterest( uint256 _loanAmount) public view returns (uint256) {
   return _loanAmount * (100 + interestPercentage) / 100 - _loanAmount;
}
```